# Edit and use powershell output as variable

Tags: powershell, cmd

*I want to use my pc's ServiceTag as output but i need to delete "SerialNumber" text first.*

**my code:**

```
cls   
$tag = wmic bios get serialnumber    
$tag
```

**Output:**

```
SerialNumber

JPX9832X31Z
```

i need **JPX9832X31Z** as **$tag**

Comment: In addition to the provided answer, you can use  `$tag = (get-ciminstance -classname win32_bios).SerialNumber`

Comment: When I run `wmic.exe /?` on Windows 10, the message appears `"WMIC is deprecated."` Use `Get-CimInstance`. `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_BIOS).SerialNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to split the string based on new line and select the `2nd` index.

```
$WMiResult = wmic bios get serialnumber
$tag = ($WMiResult -split "\n")[2]
$tag
```

Alternatively you can also use `Select-Object` Cmdlet.

```
$tag = wmic bios get serialnumber | Select-Object -Index 2
```

Comment: sir thanks for your help. have a nice day ^^